# How do you not toggle Switch when hitting enter twice on a keyboard in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-switch

When pressing enter twice on the editText "textbox" the first push will submit the button as usual, but the second press will toggle the switch.  How do I ensure that the switch does not get toggled?

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/textbox"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />

      <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="left" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Either Set it to not be clickable or to make sure it stays in the same isChecked status, either will work.

```
    switch.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener{
      override fun onKey(v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          when(keyCode){
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ->{
             // switch.isClickable = false
              if (!switch.isChecked){
                !switch.isChecked
              }else{
                switch.isChecked
              }

              return true
            }
          }
        }

//        switch.isClickable = true
        return false
      }
    })
```